# Combine multiple images with same name

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a folder called "Images" and one called "Mask". In the "Image" folder there are 200 images and in the "Mask" folder there are 200 images (with transparent background) with the same name. I now want to combine always the two pictures with the same name, so the image form the "Image" folder is in the background. The image are the same size.

Example Background image:

[image]

Example Mask:

[image]

I guess it should be quite easily doable with imagemagick, but i don't really now this program and the examples I found are all way more sophisticated.

I tried something like that:

```
convert Images/*.png -draw "image over x,y 0,0 Mask/*.png" combined/*.png
```

Did it not work because of the path? Do I have to to a loop, or is there a easy way?

Thanks

Comment: Are you on Windows? Or a decent OS? Please provide sample input image, mask and output image for testing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Decent one ;) Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Does your sample code do what you want if you just use a single image?

Comment: @MarkSetchellI found a method with an other command :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have lots of images, and it will do all the loops and filename/directory splitting for you, I would use **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
mkdir -p combined
parallel 'convert {} Mask/{/} -composite combined/{/}' ::: Images/*png
```

Be very careful with `parallel` and test what you plan to do with:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

first to be sure.

`{}` means *"the current parameter"*

`{/}` means *"the current parameter stripped of the directory part"*

`:::` indicates the start of the parameters.

---

Or, you can use a loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p combined
cd Images

for f in *png; do
    convert "$f" ../Mask/"$f" -composite ../combined/"$f"
done
```

Comment: i just found a quite similar solution. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find a way with a small bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for entry in Images/*
do
  name="$(cut -d'/' -f2 <<<"$entry")"
  convert Cells/$name Mask/$name -composite combined/$name
done
```

Comment: Cool - glad you got it working. Btw, consider adding double quotes around every `"$name"` on the line commencing `convert ...`, else it won't work if there are spaces in your filenames.